# Node JS Loopback models use cases

Tags: javascript, node.js, architecture, loopbackjs

I am coming from models and controller paradigm, where models deals with DB and controllers have the business logic to serve the REST api's.

Now, i am looking into a Loopback(framework based on Node JS) to do new project with it. But, it only have model to do all kind of stuff. I am not able to understand how i can merge service layer and controller layer into models. That sounds me a bit confusing.

If any one can provide the right direction for designing a system with Loopback. That would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a new model, say `Profile`, you get 2 new files:

`profile.js
profile.json`

Consider `profile.json` as your model, actually just a declaration of your model. And consider `profile.js` as your controller. All RESTful APIs you need are dynamically generated by loopback, if you need to add additional logic to the regular APIs or create new ones, your starting point is `profile.js`.

Now, you can structure your application code as you like. I usually put all the application business logic into a service layer, having the module `profile_service.js` and referencing it from `profile.js`.